# Sinon JS "Attempted to wrap ajax which is already wrapped"

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I got the above error message when I ran my test. Below is my code (I'm using Backbone JS and Jasmine for testing). Does anyone know why this happens?

```
$(function() {
  describe("Category", function() {
     beforeEach(function() {
      category = new Category;
      sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
     }

     it("should fetch notes", function() {
      category.set({code: 123});
      category.fetchNotes();
      expect(category.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled();
     }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have to remove the spy after every test. Take a look at the example from the sinon docs:

```
{
    setUp: function () {
        sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
    },

    tearDown: function () {
        jQuery.ajax.restore(); // Unwraps the spy
    },

    "test should inspect jQuery.getJSON's usage of jQuery.ajax": function () {
        jQuery.getJSON("/some/resource");

        assert(jQuery.ajax.calledOnce);
        assertEquals("/some/resource", jQuery.ajax.getCall(0).args[0].url);
        assertEquals("json", jQuery.ajax.getCall(0).args[0].dataType);
    }
}
```

So in your jasmine test should look like this:

```
$(function() {
  describe("Category", function() {
     beforeEach(function() {
      category = new Category;
      sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
     }

     afterEach(function () {
        jQuery.ajax.restore();
     });

     it("should fetch notes", function() {
      category.set({code: 123});
      category.fetchNotes();
      expect(category.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled();
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: In one of my trials, I had an afterEach block too but it didn't solve the problem. Could it be because I put the afterEeach after all the tests instead of right after beforeEach?

Comment: I think so, cause `beforeEach`and `afterEach` are function calls just as your tests. So calling `afterEach` after all your tests will have no effect.

Comment: process.exit.restore(); ... nice

Comment: 2019...Juste add into describe block this function :

     afterEach(function () {
        jQuery.ajax.restore();
     });

or
afterEach(function () {
        $.ajax.restore();
     });

It depend your import about jQuery. often we writed "import * as $ from ..."

Comment: Was still facing this issue, thanks to my colleague who left this hole in his test cases. worked after closing it.

Answer (score 9):

What you need in the very beginning is:

```
  before ->
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()

  afterEach ->
    sandbox.restore()
```

Then call something like:

```
windowSpy = sandbox.spy windowService, 'scroll'
```

- Please notice that I use coffee script.

Comment: Unless open ended or unspecified, answers should be in the language the question is in.

Comment: @JustinJohnson I don't think there is any misunderstanding between JS and coffee script. BTW, they are the SAME language.

Comment: Your experience and that of the questioner are not the same, and you shouldn't assume that they are.  CoffeeScript adds syntactic sugar to JavaScript (which you used here), so they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: `afterEach` and calling `sandbox.restore()` plus one