# Attempting to test a React component with jasmine-react

Tags: jasmine, reactjs, stub

This question is very similar to [one of the solutions to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280428/stubbing-a-react-component-method-with-sinon).

I'm using this as my example as its similar to my real problem but nicely distilled.

The following test produces this result:

```
Warning: Comp.type is deprecated. Use Comp directly to access the class.

 Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
```

The test:

```
it("should call plop method on render", function(){

      var Comp = React.createClass({

        displayName: "Comp",

        plop: function() {
          console.log("plop");
        },

        render: function() {
          this.plop();
          return (<div></div>);
        }
      });


      //spy on method
      jasmineReact.spyOnClass(Comp, "plop");
      jasmineReact.render(<Comp />);
      expect(Comp.plop).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should you be using jasmineReact.render rather than renderIntoDocument?

Comment: If I use jasmineRect.render I get:

```Warning: Comp.type is deprecated. Use Comp directly to access the class.'

 Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.```

Comment: Are you passing a dom node as the second argument?

Comment: Just amended the question slightly so I return ```(<div></div>)``` from render method. Didn't make any difference though. Is that what you were refering to?

Comment: Amended again so instead of ```TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Comp />);``` I call ```jasmineReact.render(<Comp />);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JasmineReact's syntax for method expectations is different to the way you're using it. Try this:

```
expect(jasmineReact.classPrototype(Comp).plop).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Additionally, if you're running an expectation against something like state, you need to use the instance that `render` returns, rather than the class:

```
var comp = jasmineReact.render(<Comp />);

expect(comp.state.something).toBe('else');
```

Comment: Thanks Colin. Your first line works correctly - my bad, its mentioned in the docs. However, ``jasmineReact.render(<Comp />);`` is the line thats throwing the exception. If I change it to ```TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Comp />);``` then the whole test passes. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: jasmineReact.render assumes that you have the #jasmine_content div on your page somewhere, is it possible that's not present?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean when you say 'on the page'. Which page?  When I look at the docs for ```jsamine-react``` it has this in the comments: 

    // jasmineReact wraps React.render, so you don't have to worry
    //  about the async nature of when the actual DOM get's rendered, or selecting
    //  where your component needs to get rendered (default is #jasmine_content) Where would I put #jasmine_content ?